# Create a function in SQL for a table with a parameter for a certain column value which returns another column value in the same row for it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function

Trying to create a function for a 2 column table. The parameter should be a value for
lets say the column A value, and the functions should return the column B value for the same row.

This is a query for the table:

```
SELECT Clubs.ID, COUNT(People.ID) FROM Clubs JOIN People ON People.InClub= Clubs.ID
GROUP BY Clubs.ID
```

This returns me the following table (shortened for example):
It shows how many people using COUNT(People.ID) are in a club with an
ID 56, 57 etc.

| ID | COUNT(People.ID) |
| --- | --- |
| 56 | 9 |
| 57 | 6 |
| 32 | 4 |
| 78 | 3 |

Now I'm trying to create a function for it, that takes a club ID
as its parameter and returns the COUNT(People.ID) for it.

I've tried the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_clubsize(club_id integer)
RETURNS integer
BEGIN
DECLARE members integer;
    SELECT COUNT(People.ID)
    INTO members
    FROM Clubs
    JOIN People ON People.inClub= Clubs.ID
    WHERE Clubs.ID = club_id
    GROUP BY COUNT(People.ID)
    RETURN members;
END
```

However, this gives me the following error:
"Syntax error near 'RETURN' on line 11 (Watcom SQL)
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State = "42000"
Line 11"

So for example, if I were to call this function SELECT * f_clubsize(56), it would return me 9.

How should I go on about this? Did not find anything worthwhile in google. I don't understand my logic error here either, I suck with SQL.

It is indeed for an assignment, requires that I create a function.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: create this view `SELECT Clubs.ID as ID, COUNT(People.ID) as B FROM Clubs JOIN People ON People.InClub= Clubs.ID
GROUP BY Clubs.ID`, then just `select B from the_view where ID= [desired value]`

Comment: it's for an assignment where in need of creating a function. will add it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION f_clubsize(club_id integer)
RETURNS integer
BEGIN
    DECLARE members integer;

    SELECT COUNT(People.ID) INTO members
    FROM Clubs
    JOIN People ON People.inClub = Clubs.ID
    WHERE Clubs.ID = club_id;

    RETURN members;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

You need to change the delimiter when creating the function, since there are multiple statements in the function body. You can remove the group by since you are filtering by ID in the WHERE. You are also missing a semicolon to terminate the SELECT.